# Avoiding Repetitive Code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

this time I am working on a project that involves music playing every hour, for the full hour on an html page. The thing is. . .every hour a different song will play. Yep. That means I have 24 different `<audio>` tags in my html (and I'm fine with that, assuming there is no way to use less code.). Now, the part where things get tricky is in the JavaScript. Here is my code to make each song play each hour.

```js
   var curHour = new Date().getHours(); //finds the current hour
   //grabs the music
  var music1 = document.getElementById('music1');
 var music2 = document.getElementById('music2');
 var music3 = document.getElementById('music3');
 var music4 = document.getElementById('music4');
 var music5 = document.getElementById('music5');
 var music6 = document.getElementById('music6');
 var music7 = document.getElementById('music7');
 var music8 = document.getElementById('music8');
 var music9 = document.getElementById('music9');
 var music10 = document.getElementById('music10');
 var music11 = document.getElementById('music11');
 var music12 = document.getElementById('music12');
 //etc. etc. etc.

  //tells the music when to play
 if (curHour === 1) { 
  music1.play(); 
 }
 else if (curHour === 2) {
  music2.play();
 }
 else if (curHour === 3) {
  music3.play();
 }
//etc. etc. etc.
```

As you can see, this code seems WAY too repetitive!
In attempts to 'clean up' the code, I've tried `for()` loops, though I've only gotten half way through them before realizing that the way I was doing it would make telling a song (in the form of a variable) to play impossible. 
I've also tried something along the lines of:

```js
var grab = document.getElementById;
var hourMusic = [grab('music1'), grab('music2')];
if (curHour === 10) {
  hourMusic[0].play()
  }
else {
  hourMusic[1].play()
  }
```

This didn't work. . . and the more I look at it seems kinda dumb of me to think that'd work. But hey, at least I can say I tried (Even though you probably can't save document.getElementById by itself in a variable).

Comment: Hint: `document.getElementById("music" + curHour).play()`.

Comment: Hint: `var music = new Array(12); music[index] = document.getElementById('music'+index);` (Although, as Xufox implies you don't need the array at all)

Comment: Regarding the short block of code at the end, it doesn't work because of the `grab` function. If you changed it to `var grab = document.getElementById.bind(document);` or just used `document.getElementById()` directly it should work. But whether to use a shortcut to that function is just a distraction from what you're trying to implement here.

Comment: @Xufox I tried your way, and it works fine! I just need to remember to change the id of my first audio tag to 'music0', since time in JavaScript begins at 0. . .

Comment: @BrettCarwile Note that this was just one hint. There are multiple ways to do this, far shorter than that.

Comment: @Xufox well thanks anyways for pointing me in the right direction!!! I cannot fully express how thankful I am for the Stack Overflow community!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you only create a single `<audio>` element and just overwrite its `src` attribute to change songs, rather than creating one `<audio>` element for every single hour of the day.

On page load you can call a function to retrieve the current hour and the corresponding song URL for that hour, set the `src` attribute of the singular `<audio>` element to that URL, and play it. You can also call the function when playback ends using the `onended` event to implement looping playback, and additionally to change the song at the turn of the hour.

```js
// note: I was lazy and just repeated 3 URLs 8 times
var songDir = 'http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/';
var songURLs = [
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2001.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2002.mp3',
    songDir+'Bach%20-%20Jesu,%20Joy%20of%20Man\'s%20Desiring.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2001.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2002.mp3',
    songDir+'Bach%20-%20Jesu,%20Joy%20of%20Man\'s%20Desiring.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2001.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2002.mp3',
    songDir+'Bach%20-%20Jesu,%20Joy%20of%20Man\'s%20Desiring.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2001.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2002.mp3',
    songDir+'Bach%20-%20Jesu,%20Joy%20of%20Man\'s%20Desiring.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2001.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2002.mp3',
    songDir+'Bach%20-%20Jesu,%20Joy%20of%20Man\'s%20Desiring.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2001.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2002.mp3',
    songDir+'Bach%20-%20Jesu,%20Joy%20of%20Man\'s%20Desiring.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2001.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2002.mp3',
    songDir+'Bach%20-%20Jesu,%20Joy%20of%20Man\'s%20Desiring.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2001.mp3',
    songDir+'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2002.mp3',
    songDir+'Bach%20-%20Jesu,%20Joy%20of%20Man\'s%20Desiring.mp3',
];

window.playSongByHour = function(hour) {
    let audioElem = document.getElementById('audio1');
    audioElem.setAttribute('src',songURLs[hour]); // hour must be in 0:23
    audioElem.play();
}; // end function()
window.playSongByCurrentHour = function() { playSongByHour(new Date().getHours()); };
```

```html
<body onload="playSongByCurrentHour();">
    <audio id="audio1" controls="1" onended="playSongByCurrentHour();"/>
</body>
```